# Infinite sequences of integers is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

An example presented in my course notes is that **the set of all infinite sequences of integers is uncountable**.

To prove this, my professor elected to assume that this set were countable, and provided a contradiction similar to Cantor's diagonalization argument, defining a sequence which could not be equal to some sequence in our denumerable set.

Out of curiosity however I think I came up with another proof employing cardinal arithmetic, and wanted to know if it looks okay. My primary concern is whether it is correct and reasonable to simply state that this set is expressible by $\mathbb{N}^{Z}$.

---

**Proof**:

This set of infinite sequences is expressible via $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{Z}}$. Then 
$$
\left|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{Z}}\right| = \left|\mathbb{N}\right|^{|\mathbb{Z}|} = \aleph_{0}^{\aleph_{0}} \leq (2^{\aleph_{0}})^{\aleph_{0}} = 2^{(\aleph_{0}\cdot \aleph_{0})} = 2^{\aleph_{0}} \leq \aleph_{0}^{\aleph_{0}}
$$
shows that $\left|\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{Z}}\right| = c$ and thus it is uncountable. $\square$

Comment: How do you know $\aleph_0 \le 2^{\aleph_0} $?  I'm not saying this is wrong but I suspect it may be circular.  Basically infinite sequences is equivalent to real numbers.  This isn't *similar* to cantor's diagonal.  It *is* cantor's diagonal.  So... I'm not sure it's legitimate (if we haven't yet proven $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable) or significant (if we have).    At least that's my impression.... but, no, it is not wrong.

Comment: It is enough to show that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @fleablood Ah yeah, you bring up a good point - it should be mentioned or more explicitly shown that $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ is uncountable. I would more explicitly use a theorem that states $|X| <|\mathcal{P}(X)|$ to justify $\aleph_{0} \leq 2^{\aleph_{0}}$ I guess.

Comment: Actually the set of infinite sequences of integers is $\mathbb{Z^N}$, not $\mathbb{N^Z}$ (which would be the set of doubly-infinite sequences of _naturals_). Fortunately this doesn't change anything important here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Wow, thanks a lot! Turns out I've been writing this notation incorrectly for a few weeks and never docked marks on assignments/etc. so I never realized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is fine. Although just to prove that $\Bbb{N^Z}$ is uncountable you only need to argue that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$, which is trivial, and then that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is already uncountable.