# Is this proof for countability correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Conjecture: The set A = {(a1, a2, a3,..)} of infinite sequence of integers is  countably infinite.

I think that this is true (correct me if I'm wrong) but I'm not sure if my proof is correct. Can someone help?

Here's my proof:

Firstly, we agree to list the sequence in an increasing order, i.e. a1≤a2≤a3.... so on.
Then we can list the elements of A as follows:

Compare the first entry in the tuples(a1). Then arrange the tuples in an increasing order of them. Repeat the same for the second entry and so on...
By the end, we would have a list of the elements of A. Thus it is countably infinite.

I highly doubt the validity of this "sorting the tuples" proof. If it's wrong, please also supply a correct proof.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's true; cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970162/infinite-sequences-of-integers-is-uncountable)

Comment: Thanks for the reference

Comment: Your set $A$ is a singleton, of course it's countable.

Comment: Even the set of binary sequences is uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is false. There are two fairly instructive ways to show this. It is perhaps easier to think of $A$ as the set of *functions* $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$.

---

First, $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ bijects naturally with the set of functions $\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ by mapping a set $S\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ to its indicator function $\mathbf 1_S(n)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }n\in S\\0\text{ if }n\not\in S\end{cases}$. So $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ injects into $A$, hence $A$ is uncountable.

---

Alternatively, we can use Cantor's diagonal argument. Suppose $A$ is countable, list it as $f_1,f_2,\dots$. Then define $f(n)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }f_n(n)\neq 1\\2\text{ if }f_n(n)=1\end{cases}$. But $f$ is not on the list of $f_1,f_2,\dots$, contradiction.

---

What is true though is that the set $B$ of functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$ with *finite support* is countable (i.e. in your original notation, the set of integer sequences that are eventually constantly $0$).

Comment: In set theory "integers" will often refer to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila that is not a convention I was aware of! Not that it really makes a difference in these countability questions of course.

Comment: Thanks @jlammy !

Answer (score 1):

As to where your proof fails:

> Firstly, we agree to list the sequence in an increasing order, i.e. a1≤a2≤a3.... so on.

1. Many sequences do not have a least element to act as $a_1$, for example, the sequence $-1, -2, -3, \ldots$.

To avoid this, let's just talk about sequences of *natural* numbers instead. Then we have a least element always. But:

2. For any increasing sequence that is not eventually constant, there are infinitely many sequences which when reordered to be increasing will give that same sequence. So by making this reordering, you are treating all of those infinitely many sequences as if they were only one. For example, all of the following sequences reorder to be $1,2,3,\ldots$:

   - $2,1,4,3,6,5,\ldots$
   - $2,1,3,4,5,7,6,\ldots$
   - $2,1,3,5,4,7,9,11,6,\ldots$
   - $\ldots$

Alright, to sidestep that issue, let's just restrict our attention to increasing sequences right from the start. Then we can proceed.

> Then we can list the elements of A as follows:
>
> Compare the first entry in the tuples(a1). Then arrange the tuples in an increasing order of them.

3. There are infinitely many increasing sequences that start with $1$. For example

   - $1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$
   - $1,3,4,5,6,\ldots$
   - $1,4,5,6,7,\ldots$
   - $\ldots$

So you will have completely filled out your "countable" list before even reaching the sequences that start with $2$.